# In visual studio experimental instance I need to remove keyboard shortcut for "Cut" and "Delete" in Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, vsix

I am trying to remove keyboard shortcut for CUT and Delete in experimental instance for Solution Explorer.
The below code is working globally (For entire visual studio its restricting).
I need to restrict it to Solution explorer, when we click on any specific file, Cut and Delete keyboard shortcuts should not work.

This is my code snippet that I have tried:

```
DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));
Command command = dte.Commands.Item("Edit.Cut", -1);

if (command.Bindings != null)
{
   command.Bindings = new object[];
}
```

Comment: Where id the code you put in?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite tricky, so bear with me here.

Quote from [Ripping the Visual Studio Editor Apart with Projection Buffers](https://joshvarty.com/2014/08/01/ripping-the-visual-studio-editor-apart-with-projection-buffers/):

> Visual Studio uses the [command chain design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) to route commands. Essentially, a linked list is created of different components (all inheriting from [`IOleCommandTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.ole.interop.iolecommandtarget?view=visualstudiosdk-2022)) that are interested in listening to commands. Basic commands include <kbd>arrow</kbd> key presses, <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd>, and <kbd>backspace</kbd>. For just a sampling of the many possible commands see [VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vsconstants.vsstd97cmdid?view=visualstudiosdk-2022&redirectedfrom=MSDN).

With that information, we can imagine something like getting the [`WindowPane`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.windowpane?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) (which implements the [`IOleCommandTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.ole.interop.iolecommandtarget?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) interface) of the Solution Explorer window and trying to change its command target. After a few searches, I got this:

```cs
// get the solution explorer window, note that you need to make sure it is loaded at the time
var solutionExplorerWindow = await VS.Windows.GetSolutionExplorerWindowAsync();
solutionExplorerWindow.Frame.GetProperty((int)__VSFPROPID.VSFPROPID_DocView, out object property);

// note that it is not actually `ToolWindowPane`, but an internal derived class
ToolWindowPane solutionExplorerPane = property as ToolWindowPane;
```

After that, I set a breakpoint to check what fields it has, and saw that it has a `IOleCommandTarget _commandTarget` field, which is pretty self-explainatory. Now we just need to change it to our own [`IOleCommandTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.ole.interop.iolecommandtarget?view=visualstudiosdk-2022). The tricky thing is, the field is private, and the class is an internal one. So we need to do some reflection magics:

```cs
FieldInfo commandTargetField = solutionExplorerPane.GetType().BaseType.GetField("_commandTarget", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

// get the original command target
var originalCommandTarget = commandTargetField.GetValue(solutionExplorerPane) as IOleCommandTarget;

// create out command handler, with the orignal command target
CommandHandler commandHandler = new(originalCommandTarget);

// "hook" its command target
commandTargetField.SetValue(solutionExplorerPane, commandHandler);
```

In the code snippet above, we get its `_commandTarget`, and construct our own `CommandHandler` to override the original one, basically a hook. Here is how `CommandHandler` was implemented:

```cs
internal class CommandHandler : IOleCommandTarget
{
    private readonly IOleCommandTarget _commandTarget;

    internal CommandHandler(IOleCommandTarget commandTarget)
    {
        _commandTarget = commandTarget;
    }

    public DesignerVerbCollection Verbs => throw new NotImplementedException();

    // Disable this warning because this will always be executed on the main thread
#pragma warning disable VSTHRD010 // Invoke single-threaded types on Main thread

    // This method will be called to check if we can handle the command or not
    public int QueryStatus(ref Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint cCmds, OLECMD[] prgCmds, IntPtr pCmdText)
    {
        // do this if you want to hide the button on the "Edit" tool bar
        if (pguidCmdGroup == VSConstants.CMDSETID.StandardCommandSet97_guid)
        {
            for (uint i = 0; i < prgCmds.Length; i++)
            {
                if (prgCmds[i].cmdID == (uint)VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID.Cut ||
                    prgCmds[i].cmdID == (uint)VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID.Delete)
                {
                    prgCmds[i].cmdf = (uint)(OLECMDF.OLECMDF_INVISIBLE | OLECMDF.OLECMDF_DEFHIDEONCTXTMENU);
                }
            }
        }
        return _commandTarget.QueryStatus(pguidCmdGroup, cCmds, prgCmds, pCmdText);
    }

    // This method will be called to actually execute the command
    public int Exec(ref Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut)
    {
        if (pguidCmdGroup == VSConstants.CMDSETID.StandardCommandSet97_guid)
        {
            if (nCmdID == (uint)VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID.Cut ||
                nCmdID == (uint)VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID.Delete)
            {
                return VSConstants.S_OK;
            }
        }
        return _commandTarget.Exec(pguidCmdGroup, nCmdID, nCmdexecopt, pvaIn, pvaOut);
    }
#pragma warning restore VSTHRD010 // Invoke single-threaded types on Main thread
}
```

Be aware that there are other command set that you might want to check for as well, such as the [`VSConstants.VSStd2KCmdID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vsconstants.vsstd2kcmdid?view=visualstudiosdk-2022).